# How to run an Express app with powershell

Tags: node.js, powershell, express

I want to run an ExpressJS app by using Powershell. It works with cmd when I use `SET DEBUG=myApp:* & npm start`, but it won't work in the powershell.  The error message is as follows:

```
At line:1 char:24
+ SET DEBUG=helloworld:* & npm start
+                        ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo: ParserError: (:) [],ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

I've tried to eliminate the ampersand or wrap it around quotations marks but to no avail; I keep getting further error messages.  I've googled this but haven't found the answer.

I want to know what is the command to be used in powershell  to run my ExpressJS app.

By using some other commands suggested by other users, I get the following error:

PS C:\Users\User\myNode\helloworld> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DEBUG","helloworld:*"‌​); & npm start
At line:1 char:61
+ [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DEBUG","helloworld:*"‌​); & np ...
+                                                             ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:61
+ ... Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DEBUG","helloworld:*"‌​); & npm ...
+                                                                ~~
Unexpected token '‌​' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:63
+ ... nvironment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DEBUG","helloworld:*"‌​); & npm  ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall

PS C:\Users\User\myNode\helloworld> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DEBUG","helloworld:* & npm start")
PS C:\Users\User\myNode\helloworld>

Comment: `$env:DEBUG='helloword:*'; npm start`

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting errors with that command

Comment: Can you show more of your code and where you are using `Debug`? Without seeing more we are guessing at what you are looking to do. One of these may be what you are looking for: `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DEBUG","helloworld:*"); & npm start` or `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DEBUG","helloworld:* & npm start")`

Comment: I've edited my question, including the error I get by using:

Comment: [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DEBUG","helloworld:*"‌​); & npm start

Comment: The error is from having an invisible junk extra character between `"` and `)`.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I'll have a look.

Answer (score 4):

PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\myapp> set DEBUG='myapp:*'; npm start

Answer (score 2):

The following worked great for me using powershell.

```
PS > [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DEBUG","express:*"); & npm start

> <hidden_data>@0.0.0 start C:\<hidden_data>
> node ./bin/www

  express:router:route new '/' +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router:route get '/' +15ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router:route new '/' +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router:route get '/' +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:application set "x-powered-by" to true +0ms
  express:application set "etag" to 'weak' +0ms
  express:application set "etag fn" to [Function: generateETag] +0ms
  express:application set "env" to 'development' +0ms
  express:application set "query parser" to 'extended' +0ms
  express:application set "query parser fn" to [Function: parseExtendedQueryString] +0ms
  express:application set "subdomain offset" to 2 +16ms
  express:application set "trust proxy" to false +0ms
  express:application set "trust proxy fn" to [Function: trustNone] +0ms
  express:application booting in development mode +3ms
  express:application set "view" to [Function: View] +1ms
  ...
  <hidden_data>
  ...
  express:application set "jsonp callback name" to 'callback' +1ms
  express:application set "views" to 'C:\\1d\\MaterialDesignComponentsPjs\\ExpressAppGeneratorPjs\\pioneer-towers-res-assoc-sass\\views' +1ms
  express:application set "view engine" to 'pug' +1ms
  express:router use '/' query +2ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router use '/' expressInit +1ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router use '/' logger +1ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router use '/' jsonParser +2ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router use '/' urlencodedParser +1ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router use '/' cookieParser +1ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router use '/' sass +2ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router use '/' serveStatic +1ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router use '/' router +1ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router use '/users' router +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/users' +1ms
  express:router use '/' <anonymous> +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router use '/' <anonymous> +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:application set "port" to 3000 +1ms
  express:router dispatching GET / +29s
  express:router query  : / +4ms
  express:router expressInit  : / +2ms
  express:router logger  : / +1ms
  express:router jsonParser  : / +5ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : / +1ms
  express:router cookieParser  : / +1ms
  express:router sass  : / +1ms
  express:router serveStatic  : / +6ms
  express:router router  : / +5ms
  express:router dispatching GET / +1ms
  express:view require "pug" +2ms
  express:view lookup "index.pug" +680ms
  <hidden_data>
GET / 304 782.513 ms - -
```

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS or Linux, run the app with this command:

```
$ DEBUG=myapp:* npm start
```

On Windows Command Prompt, use this command:

```
> set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start
```

On Windows PowerShell, use this command:

```
PS> $env:DEBUG='myapp:*'; npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, found a solution by correcting - & -  to - ';

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in VisualStudio's terminal or Powershell:

```
SET DEBUG=appwebPUG:* | npm start
```

Only change & for |

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```js
process.env.DEBUG = 'app';
const debug = require('debug')('app')
```

terminal

```bash
set DEBUG=app    # shift + Enter to move to second line
node app.js
```

This way you don't have to use the & char